# Using an or operator to assign a value to an object

Tags: javascript

I have an identity function:

```
theIdentity = function(val) {
    return val;
 };
```

And a function that is going to reduce an array:

```
theReduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    iterator = iterator || theIdentity;
};
```

I am having trouble understanding this line:

```
iterator = iterator || theIdentity;
```

I know it is supposed to check if the iterator is undefined and assign it as theIdentity if it is, but anymore insight would be appreciated.

Comment: it simply means if iterator is not false, null or undefined then use that, otherwise use theIdentity variable.

Answer (score -1):

It is short-hand for:

```
if(iterator) 
   iterator = iterator
else 
   iterator = theIdentity;
```